# how do I change the name attribute of a form in ie 7?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, name-attribute

Sometimes when I work with third party scripts, I have to do things like change the name of a form in order to get their code to work properly. This works perfectly in all browsers except in IE 7.

After googling and searching stackoverflow, I have come to the understanding that in IE 7 the name attribute can only be set when creating the element (correct me if I am wrong). I want to ask if anyone can suggest a work around other than creating another form (which is huge and has several elements).

I have put it up on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/urTdq/

Code:

```
<form name="oldForm" id="form">
</form>
<a href="#" id="change">Change Form Name</a>
<script>
$("#change").click(function() {
$("#form").attr("name", "newForm");
});
</script>
```

Let me know if you need more clarification/info. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like IE creates a new attribute `submitName`: http://jsfiddle.net/vasek7/efCqh/embedded/result/. You need this to access the form like `document.newForm`?

Comment: yes you are right. I need to be able to access the form like document.newForm. It creates a new attribute 'submitName' which the javascript does not recognize.

Comment: turns out there is not really a good way to do this. Basically, I had to rewrite the code so the form name would be a non-issue.